# JAX-WS standalone client with ws-security timestamp token

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, ws-security

I created an application with a standalone webservice client implemented with JAX-WS (using wsimport).

Now the customer asked me to add ws-security feature signing a timestamp tag in the soap header.

I'm actually in crisis because I have not idea how to add this feature in this project, without make a new one. Someone suggested me to use CXF, but I'd like to keep the actual project with JAX-WS.

There is a way to add ws-security feature in jax-ws? JAX-WS classes have been generated with wsimport starting from wdsl and xsd files provided me by the customer.

Thanks...

Comment: Are you using Spring? I don't thing you need a new project.

Comment: actually I'm not using Spring, but I can add support to Spring if needed. What could you suggest me? Thanks!

Comment: With Spring, you develop a Web service client/server side without security and then, you can add the security using interceptors without changing a line of code. Take a look to the doc, even if you are not using spring, the idea/concept of "interceptors" can help you. See http://goo.gl/47vwy